# Calculation of renewal function $R(t) = \sum{F^n(t)}$?

Tags: summation, stochastic-processes, convolution

My textbook defines the renewal function $R(t) = E[N_t] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F^n(t)$, where $F^n(t)$ appears to be the n-fold convolution of $F$ with itself. $F$ is the distribution of the interrenewal times in a renewal process. I'm not sure how to actually calculate this though.

I'm kind of struggling with the idea of convolution, which might be why I can't figure this out.

One specific example gives $F(t) = 1 - e^{-3t} - 3te^{-3t}$. I'm unsure how to find $R(t)$ given this though. $R = 1 + F + F^2 + F^3  + \cdots$, but the definition of convolution seems too complex to me for there to be a good direct way to calculate this sum. Is there any easier way to solve for $R$?

Thanks.

EDIT:

... I still haven't figured this out. If I use the renewal equation, $R = F + R*F$, in this example, I have:

$R = 1 - e^{-3t} -3te^{-3t} + (R * (1 - e^{-3t} -3te^{-3t}))$

$R = 1 - e^{-3t} -3te^{-3t} + \int_0^t{F(t-x)dR(x)}$ by the definition of convolution.

$R = 1 - e^{-3t} -3te^{-3t} + \int_0^t{(1-e^{-3(t-x)}-3(t-x)e^{-3(t-x)})dR(x) }$

But I can't calculate this integral since I don't know what $R(x)$ is. At this point, I was thinking of differentiating with respect $R(x)$ but I'm  not sure if this would actually work.

Comment: Recall the renewal equation $R = F+R\star F$.

Comment: I found the renewal equation to be defined $f = g + F * f$ in my textbook, where the only solution is at $f = R*g$. So $R*g = g + F * (R*g)$. Are these equivalent?

Comment: If so, would I just "plug and chug" to solve for R? It still doesn't seem so easy to solve with that equation - when calculating $R*F$, I still need to know $dR(x)$. Would I need to take the derivative, $d/dt$ of both sides get to the solution?

Comment: The discussion above mentions that the CDF $R$ solves $R=F+R\ast F$, that is, $$R(t)=F(t)+\int_0^tf(x)R(t-x)dx.$$ Thus, the PDF $r=R'$ solves $r=f+f\ast R$, that is, $$r(t)=f(t)+\int_0^tf(x)r(t-x)dx=f(t)+\int_0^tf(t-x)r(x)dx,$$ or, equivalently since $f(t)=9te^{-3t}$, $$e^{3t}r(t)=9t+9t\int_0^te^{3x}r(x)dx-9\int_0^txe^{3x}r(x)dx,$$ hence $$(e^{3t}r(t))'=9+9\int_0^te^{3x}r(x)dx,$$ that is, $$(e^{3t}r(t))''=9(e^{3t}r(t)),$$
which yields $$e^{3t}r(t)=Ae^{3t}+Be^{-3t},$$ that is, $$r(t)=A+Be^{-6t}.$$
Now, $r(0)=f(0)=0$ and $r'(0)=9$ hence $A+B=0$ and $-6B=9$, that is $$r(t)=\frac32(1-e^{-6t}).$$